# Comment deletion requires manual page refresh to disappearing

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

At least on two sites: [Stack Overflow on Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) and [Russian Language Stack Exchange](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) if you delete your comment it doesn’t disappear automatically as it was always but need to refresh page manually. Before refreshing delete button is displayed in red color:

> [image: Deleted comment]

[**Jing Screencast Video**](https://www.screencast.com/t/Tor0n7mMK)

**DevTools Console error message:**

> cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.ru.js?v=313e2d72d793:6
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

[image: DevTools error]

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359206/posting-and-deleting-the-first-comment-on-a-post-causes-the-comment-to-be-shown

Comment: @JonClements didn’t see it. Already 2 days old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed that up earlier today. Long story short, we had a typo in the javascript that was responsible for hiding/removing the comment from the view. Thanks for the report!